# Core data deleting rules

Tags: objective-c, core-data

My database has 3 entities: photos, places (where photos are taken) and tags (of photos).

[image: database]

Each photo has a relationship to the place in which it has been taken.
Each place has a set of photos taken in it.

Each photo has a set of tags, and each tag has a set of photos. This is a many-to-many relationship, because a single photo can have multiple tags, and a tag can be associated with multiple photos.

Now, I can't figure out the right deleting rules for this behaviour:

- I want to directly delete only photo entities.
- If the related place has other photos taken in it, it should not be deleted. If the photo was the last photo for that place, it should be deleted.
- It the related tags appears in other photos, they should not be deleted until there are no other photos associated.
- In addition, in the tag entity I have an attribute that keep track of the number of photos associated with it (I update this attribute when I add a new photos and also in photo's prepareForDeletion).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, thank to Marcus, i've set all the deleting rules to `Nullify`, and then i wrote this code in the Photos's `prepareForDeletion`:

```
- (void)prepareForDeletion
{    
    //tag check: if this photo was the last associated with that tag, deletion !!
    for (Tag *tag in self.tags) {
        if ([tag.taggedPhotos count] == 1) {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:tag];
        } else {
            tag.photoCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[tag.photoCount intValue]-1];
        }
    }

    //place check: if this photo was the last associated with that place, deletion !!
    if ([self.whereTaken.photos count] == 1) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.whereTaken];
    }
}
```

I have not deleted the `numberOfPhotosTagged` attribute, since i'm using it to sort the tags.

Answer (score 2):

First, the tag should not need a separate attribute to keep track of the number of photos.   You can query the relationship for that count.

Second, you would want to set up a `-prepareForDeletion` in the `Photo` entity that checks to see if it is the only photo with a reference to the tag and then deletes it if that is true.

Likewise, when you delete the photo, in its `-prepareForDeletion` you can check to see how many photos are in that place and invoke the same logic.

In the model itself I would then set the delete rule to just be nullify.

Comment: i used the "numberOfPhotosTagged" attribute to sort tags (most used first).. this was the sort descriptor:
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"numberOfPhotosTagged" ascending:NO]

Comment: Ahh, you should be able to use `tags.count` as a sort descriptor instead and avoid having to keep the value in sync.  Not tested so no guarantee but it *should* work.

Comment: since i'm sorting tags, i used '[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"taggedPhotos.@count" ascending:NO]' but the program ends whit this error: 'Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle taggedPhotos.@count'

Comment: @Ciampo Remove the `@`, it should just be @"taggedPhotos.count"

Comment: not working: it says `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'`. I've put again the `photoCount` attribute, so it's working.

Comment: Interesting,  I will need to play with it as I know there is a way to touch count directly but it is not coming to me off the top of my head.  I will add a comment when I remember it.